# Is the wavelength of matter proportional to momentum or uncertainty thereof?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavelength, wave-particle-duality, matter

I am confused about de Broglie waves and their relationship with the uncertainty principle.  Both have similar formula and seem to be the same thing with a slight conceptual difference.  De Broglie waves predict that matter has a wavelength proportionate momentum whereas uncertainty claims the uncertainty of the position of matter is proportionate to the uncertainty of momentum.  Assuming the wave represents uncertainty the two formula are basically just off by 1/4*pi .
So are these the same concept or are they different?

Comment: You mean *inversely* proportional.

Comment: I am not so concerned with the semantic details.

Comment: $\lambda\propto p$ vs. $\lambda\propto 1/p$ is hardly a “semantic detail”. You have the physics exactly backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

de Broglie waves were the hypothesis, pre-quantum theory, that particles can be represented as a matter wave. In treatments of mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics the matter wave is replaced by a probability amplitude, defined by the Born rule. The probability amplitude is not, in general, assumed to be material, but is a way to represent the probability for where the particle will be found.

Uncertainty is a measure of the spread of the probability distribution. This is a different concept from the probability amplitude, but it can be calculated from the probability amplitude.

Comment: Does this then imply that de Broglie matter waves are deprecated in some way?

Comment: They were historically important, but I cannot regard them as properly a part of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Is there no true analog that is in your opinion properly part of quantum mechanics?

Comment: The wave function, or probability amplitude, is an analogue, but in de Broglie's hypothesis even macroscopic matter had a de Broglie wave (this is not true in qm, in which probabilities exist prior to measurement) and the de Broglie wave described a material property, not a mathematical probability.

Comment: Is the calculation the same?

Comment: There are "interpretations" in which the probability amplitude is taken to be a de Broglie wave. I cannot regard them.

Comment: Do you regard as the formula for probability amplitude?